# Assert all values in IntArray are equal to each other

Tags: kotlin

I have a variable `table` which is of  type `ArrayList<IntArray>?`. I want to write a test to make sure all the values in the arrays are equal to 1. Now I use a double `for` loop like:

```
        tables?.let {
            for (table in it) {
                for (value in table) {
                    Assert.assertEquals(1, value)
                }
             }
        }
```

Is there a better way to assert values in an `IntArray` are equal to each other?

Comment: You may try using [`all`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/all.html). But that would be almost like `for(_ in _)`.

Comment: `tables?.run { Assert.assertTrue(all { it.all { value -> value == 1 } }) }`

Comment: @Tenfour post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `tables` property intentionally nullable in the test? More specifically, should your test pass regardless of whether or not `tables` is null? I would suspect not, so you may wish to explicitly dereference the `tables` property.

The simplest way to do this would be to flat map the table to a list:

```
tables!!.flatMap { it.asIterable() }.forEach { assertEquals(1, it) }
```

However, I would recommend improving this a bit for test readability in the case of failure:

```
tables!!.withIndex()
  .flatMap { (row, values) -> 
    values.withIndex().map { (col, value) -> row to col to value } 
  }
  .forEach { (point, value) -> 
    val (row, col) = point
    assertEquals(1, value, "Found unexpected value $value at row=$row, col=$col") 
  }
```

Which will print something like this on failure:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Found unexpected value 2 at row=1, col=0
 at FileKt.assertEquals (File.kt:15) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:9) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:-1)
```